# Detecting Rotation of UIView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, screen-rotation, nsnotification

I have created a custom view that inherits from UIView. I really need to be able to detect the rotation in my custom view class.

I have already searched online and tried both:

```
UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification

UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
```

I have added my init method below to show the code I have tried. I tried the same code in a view controller and it worked perfectly.

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {

    super.init(frame: frame)

    UIDevice.currentDevice().beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self,
        selector: "didRotate:",
        name: UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification,
        object: nil)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self,
        selector: "rotated",
        name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification,
        object: nil)
}
```

Has anyone else had a similar problem, and if so did you find a way to solve the issue?

Comment: How are you creating the instance of your `UIView` subclass?

Comment: Originally I hadn't subclassed UIView. So I had the following to create the class _ = NetworkIndicatorView(view: self.view). Then I added the subclass of UIView and forgot to do self.networkIndicatorView = NetworkIndicatorView(view: self.view). Now it detects it fine. Many thanks Clever Error.

Comment: Standard paternal observation: I can think of almost zero occasions when it has been correct for a view to know the device orientation. Make sure that's what you really want. 99.99999% of the time your view should just decide its layout based on its bounds.

Comment: Hi Tommy. I am currently creating my indicator view and adding it to the view of my controller. I don't want to rely on the rotation of the view controller because I want the class to be self contained. However when I rotate the device I need to move the indicator. How would I do that using the bounds? Or do I need to find a new approach? Many thanks.